# string.replace var output

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Hi could some one show me how to do the following:

```
var regep = /margin-bottom:([^;]+); margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:([^;]+);/;
elementCSS = elementCSS.replace( regep , "margin-bottom:\\1; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:\\2;");
```

\1 to = ([^;]+) (margin-bottom)
and
\2 to = ([^;]+) (margin-top)

?? Cant seem to figure it out..

Regards Phil

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to dynamically adjust the top and bottom margins, it would be easier to just manipulate the element's style attributes directly with

```
element.style.marginTop = x; 
element.style.marginBottom = y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try using the Javascript **RegExp**.

- [JavaScript RegExp Example: Regular
  Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)
- [Regular Expressions patterns](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
var regep = /margin-bottom:([^;]+); margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-
top:([^;]+);/;
elementCSS = elementCSS.replace( regep , "margin-bottom:$1; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:$2;");
```